# Off canvas navigation scroling problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I made this off canvas navigation, and everything is working fine except when navigation is closed it goes all the way to top, I want it to stay where its opened. When its opened it gives body a margin of scroll position, and after closed it gives `margin: 0`. Help anyone. Here is the fiddle to make it clearer: http://jsfiddle.net/eyd7n9tk/

Edit

The point is that scrolling should be disabled but visible while navigation is opened. Following these steps:

- Open navigation anywhere on site
- Navigation opens, page stays in the same spot, does not jump anywhere
- Scrolling is disabled while navigation is opened
- Close navigation, scrolling is enabled and page is still on the same spot, without jumping.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line

```
var scrl = $(this).scrollTop();
```

And you will stay where is opened

Comment: He should also comment out line 7: $('body').scrollTop(scrl).css('margin-top', '0');

Comment: After Commenting this line will be not possible to scroll top

Comment: Yeah that does the trick, but it enables scrolling, which is something I don't want.

Comment: @OlegYudovich, he can still manually scroll. He does not need that line

Comment: Follow steps: 1.remove this line 2.scroll down 3.toggle nav 4.close nav 5.try to manually scroll up. See what happen

Comment: As I already said, It stays in the same spot, but enables scrolling while navigation is opened which is undesirable.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs it, I figured it out, just needed couple more variables that will store scroll position and nesting objects. Here is the final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eyd7n9tk/3/

```
var navigation = {};

function toggleNav() {
    navigation.scrl = $('body').scrollTop();
    if ($('#inner-wrap').hasClass('opened')) {
        $('#inner-wrap').removeClass('opened');
        $('#close-nav').hide();
        $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
        $('body').css('top', '0').scrollTop(here);
    } else {
        $('#nav').show();
        $('#inner-wrap').addClass('opened');
        $('#close-nav').show();
        $('body').css('top', - navigation.scrl + 'px').addClass('no-scroll');
    }
}

function openNav() {
    $('#nav').show();
    $('#inner-wrap').addClass('opened');
    $('#close-nav').show();
    $('body').css('top', - navigation.scrl + 'px').addClass('no-scroll');
    alert(navigation.scrl);
}

function closeNav() {
    $('#inner-wrap').removeClass('opened');
    $('#close-nav').hide();
    $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
    $('body').css('top', '0').scrollTop(navigation.scrl);
    alert(navigation.scrl);
}

$('#toggle-nav').click(function () {
    toggleNav();
});

$("#close-nav").click(function(){
    closeNav();
});
```